# Functions of One Turtle Prevents another Breed of Turtle from Executing Function

Tags: netlogo

In my model, I have multiple breeds of turtle. One is a macrophage and another is a fibroblast. Each has specific variables and specific functions to carry out. When I comment out the fibroblast function, the macrophages are able to successfully carry out their function. However, when I add the fibroblast function to the model, neither its function nor the macrophages function is properly executed. Any advice on how to resolve this?

To clarify the components of this code, activation, phagocytosis-counter, and phagocytosis-time are variables of macrophages. Repair-counter and Repair-time are variables of fibroblasts and tissue-life and collagen are variables of the patch. Thank you in advance.

`

```
to Macrophage-function


if activation > 1 and [tissue-life] of patch-at 0 0 < Phagocytosis and phagocytosis-counter = 0 and [tissue-life] of patch-at 0 0 > 0
  [ set phagocytosis-time 50
    set phagocytosis-counter 1 ]

 ifelse phagocytosis-time > 0
  [ set phagocytosis-time  phagocytosis-time - 1 ]
  [ set phagocytosis-counter 0]

  if phagocytosis-time = 1
    [ask patch-at 0 0 [set tissue-life 0]]
```

```
to Fibroblast-function

  fibroblast-movement  
  if ([tissue-life] of patch-at 0 0) < 5 and ([collagen] of patch-at 0 0 ) < 100 and repair-counter = 0  
   [set repair-time 100
      set repair-counter 1 ]

  ifelse repair-time > 0
  [ set repair-time  repair-time - 1 ]
  [ set repair-counter 0]

 if repair-time = 1
     [ ask patch-at 0 0
        [set collagen 25
         ]
    ]
```

`
I expected for the two functions to carry out independently, however, they are for some reason impairing the other.

Comment: `patch-at 0 0` can be more concisely written as `patch-here`

Comment: Have you tried running the `fibroblast-function` while commenting out the `Macrophage-function`? Can you confirm that your code doesn't get stuck in a loop somewhere? What does the rest of your code look like? Just looking at the procedures without knowing when, where, and in what context the procedures are carried out might not provide sufficient information. The following link provides a very good guide to posting helpful questions on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way to diagnose perplexing problems is to create test output: create file output that reports the variables of each agent on each time step. You will always find mistakes that need to be corrected, and that will likely make your problem go away. (You will need to do this anyway to test your code before putting it to use.)

By the way: do not use "[tissue-life] of patch-at 0 0". You should know that turtles can use the variables of the patch they are on as if they were the turtle's own variables. Replace "[tissue-life] of patch-at 0 0" with "tissue-life". This is explained in the Variables section of NetLogo's Programming Guide.